# How to use custom Scheduler in RxScala?

Tags: rx-scala

I attempt with

```
val executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
val scheduler = Schedulers.from(executors)
Observable.just[Int](1,2,3).subscribeOn(scheduler)
```

output a error

```
Error:(103, 43) type mismatch;
found   : rx.Scheduler
required: rx.lang.scala.Scheduler
Observable.just[Int](1,2,3).subscribeOn(scheduler)
                                      ^
```

how to use custom Scheduler in `RxScala`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you mix RxJava and RxScala code here. You see, RxScala is just a wrapper around the RxJava functionality; the former only forwards to the latter and does not have any 'real' implementations. This is useful as you only need to maintain 1 version rather than 2 or more.

The type of `scheduler` in your example is `rx.Scheduler`, so it is an RxJava `Scheduler`. However, `subscribeOn` requires you to provide an `rx.lang.scala.Scheduler`, which is an RxScala `Scheduler`. Hence you need to either convert the RxJava `Scheduler` to one from RxScala.

However, for your case there is a better way of doing things: wrap your `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` into a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` using the `fromExecutor` factory method. Then wrap this into an `rx.lang.scala.schedulers.ExecutionContextScheduler` and you have the scheduler you can use in `subscribeOn`. Your code will look something like this (*I included a print statement to see on which thread the stuff is running*):

```
val e = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)
val s = ExecutionContextScheduler(e)

Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    .subscribeOn(s)
    .doOnNext(x => println(s"thread - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}, value - $x"))
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: Changed executor to Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10) it always run in same thread? Any ideas?